# laravel 5.4: From is gone. What is the new way to manipulate forms?

Tags: forms, laravel

Doing something in a blade with Form in a new laravel 5.4 project, e.g.

```
{{ Form::hidden('data-name', $value->name) }}
```

will throw:

```
Class 'Form' not found
```

There are many posts with ways to try to fix this (many different and conflicting answers, some with several files needing to be edited and commands run), but my question is what is the new "correct" way to manipulate the form in laravel 5.x, seeing as it has been dropped (and adding back is non trivial)?

Currently, I have resorted to this option for laravel 5+:

```
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{ app('request')->input('token') }}">
```

Comment: This is the replacement library. https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.4/html

Answer (score 3):

Laravel externalized the management of Forms, [Here is](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.4/html) the package that implements it the way it used to be ( `{{ Form::open() }}` ), ( `{{ Form::close() }}` ) etc. All the fields are in the documentation.

Comment: It seems odd - I would have assumed blades and forms are the heart of any laravel app.  This is going to trip up any new laravel user.

Comment: You are right, answer edited to be, I hope, more new user friendly.

Comment: Thanks.  The answer now looks like it is a package to implement a legacy feature, by "the way it used to be".  This implies there is also a "way it is now"?

Comment: Normal HTML stuff  and custom logic I guess

Answer (score 1):

Run the following command

```
composer require "laravelcollective/html":"^5.4.0"
```

Next, add your new provider to the providers array of config/app.php:

```
  'providers' => [
    // ...
    Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
    // ...
  ],
```

Finally, add two class aliases to the aliases array of config/app.php:

```
  'aliases' => [
    // ...
      'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
      'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
    // ...
  ],
```