# Html Form In Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I am using laravel 5.6. when I want you to use the HTML Form in my project it gives error. even I saw the laravel collection. I can't find any HTML Form for the version of 5.6. so if anybody knows can help me in this case.

Comment: "_it gives error_" What error exactly? [Laravelcollective](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/master/html) has a Forms package

Comment: What is error? @Salim Maulaie

Comment: Possible duplicate of [laravel 5.4: From is gone. What is the new way to manipulate forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46574590/laravel-5-4-from-is-gone-what-is-the-new-way-to-manipulate-forms)

Answer (score 1):

This is no longer part of the laravel package. You will need to include the `"laravelcollective/html": "^5.4"` framework in composer, and add it appropriately to your service provider.

Comment: But it gives the error during running the form.  <?php

{{ Form::open() }}

 {{ Form::text('name', @$name) }}

 {{ Form::password('password') }}

 {{ Form::submit('Send') }}

{{ Form::close() }}


?>

Comment: Please update your original question with details of what the error are and what code you're using. The code you just commented is invalid PHP code and will error. You probably want to get rid of the php tags.